# Spring-boot kafka: How to configure two jaas conf files

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kerberos, jaas

I have a spring boot kafka client application, where i have two consumer listening to different topic and different consumer group in kafka.

In order to achieve, i need to have two JAAS conf below(using different keytab files)

**dc-jaas-A.conf**

```
    KafkaClient {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useKeyTab=true
        storeKey=true
        useTicketCache=false
        serviceName="kafka"
        keyTab="testA.keytab"
        principal="testA@domain.com";
    };
```

**dc-jaas-B.conf**

```
    KafkaClient {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useKeyTab=true
        storeKey=true
        useTicketCache=false
        serviceName="kafka"
        keyTab="testB.keytab"
        principal="testB@domain.com";
    };
```

Since below connectFactory sets the dc-jaas-A.conf and dc-jaas-B.conf in  System.setProperty, the value gets overriden and as a result i get **"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException"** exception.

```
 @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactoryForA() {
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:/Users/Files/dc-jaas-A.conf");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","C:/Users/Files/krb5.conf");
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
       // more configs here
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs);
    }
     @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactoryForB() {
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:/Users/Files/dc-jaas-B.conf");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","C:/Users/Files/krb5.conf");
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
       // more configs here
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs);
    }
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, at least with java 8. The JAAS classes internally use static structure to maintain the kerberos configuration.

You have to init/refresh krb config every time before consuming the token.

Another work around is to use same keytab file for both the SPNs. Keytab can contain multiple SPN entries.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which Kafka version you use. But you can provide JAAS configs to each Kafka client this way:

```yaml
spring.kafka:
  properties:
    security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    sasl.mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-256
    sasl.jaas.config: 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="user" password="*****";'
```